# NullPointerException when adding to Vector

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I tried to fix all but still gives same error.
Here is code, when I try to add an instance to vector that's happened. any idea?

```
private static Vector<DrawingElement> vector;

public void Add(DrawingElement de) {    
        vector.addElement(de);   // ERROR  //
        System.out.println("ADDED!");       
}
```

Comment: You have to instantiate vector firstly. It doesn't exist when you run add method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you initialized the `Vector` like so:

```
private static Vector vector = new Vector();
```

Even better, you might want to create your `Vector` as generic if it will only store objects of type `DrawingElement`:

```
private static Vector<DrawingElement> vector = new Vector<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your Vector with:

```
private static Vector vector = new Vector();
```

to avoid the NullPointerException. Once initialized, you'll be able to add elements.

Comment: Why `static`? That's no way to educate a beginner.

Comment: I see; it's just not formatted as code. I would nevertheless point out that it is wrong to have the vector `static`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the `vector` variable is not initialized. that's why you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

you have to initialize the vector. for example

```
Vector vector = new Vector();
```

or

```
Vector vector = new Vector(size);  // with the capacity
```

in your case you are adding DrawingElement class in vector so you have to initialize something like this

```
Vector<DrawingElement> vector = new Vector<DrawingElement>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In java You have to verify the object is not `null` before doing any operations over it.
If you are trying to refer an object that is not created by using `new` operator, you will
get [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

the solution for your problem would be as simple as below

```
    String s1 = "sample string1";
    String s2 = "sample string2";
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    v.add(s1);
    v.add(s2);
    Iterator<String> i = v.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the object might not yet been initialized. Use the code to fix error

```
public void add(DrawingElement de) throws IllegalStateException { 
     if (vector != null) {  
        vector.addElement(de);   // OK  //
        System.out.println("ADDED!");  
     } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR?!"); // ERROR  //
        throw new IllegalStateException("ERROR object not initialized");
     }

}
```

Comment: thanks guys, ıt was sipmle but make exhausted me !

No tricky way, do it in a simple way.
The simplest is the hardest by the way...

Comment: @blackman I guessed that the object was lazy initialized, sorry if it couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to solve.
**your code**

```
private static Vector<DrawingElement> vector;

public void Add(Vector<String> de) {    
        vector.addElement(de);   // ERROR  //
        System.out.println("ADDED!");       
}
```

**my code**

```
    vector <String> vector= new Vector();
    public void Add(DrawingElement de) {  
    vector.add(de);

}
```